# Post method not working in PHP

Tags: php, post, http-post, http-post-vars

I've tried some other posts, but never made it.

My php form inside html file is :

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
VAR:<input type="text" name="var"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I'm receiving the variable in test.php as `<br>`

`$_POST['var'] ---- > doesn't work! <br>`

`Tried, $_REQUEST['var'] ----> doesn't work!`

I tried the form using get request, it works like a charm on the other end at test.php by using both $_GET['var'] and $_REQUEST['var']
Any way I can parse the request in the form of post request from that form to test.php ..

Appreciate the help!
Thanks.

Comment: Try closing the imput tag => `<input ... />`

Comment: The tag is closed. Can you be more specific? Like line number etc..

Comment: No, it is not. Input tags must be closed by `/>`. Note the slash.

Comment: Also, in the provided code your input has no value. Is that intentional?

Comment: It is working... You are saying that it works like the charm? What doesn't work actually?

Comment: When I use method POST and try to have the variable using $_POST, I can't have the variable on test.php

Comment: Have a look in the network tab of your browser (F12) and see if you actually made a post request with the specified data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to PHP 7.0 and it's working now!

Thanks everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value of 'submit' whether it is set or not like

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$_POST['var']
}
```

Comment: should I add in test.php

Comment: it says nothing, even replacing submit with var in line 1 to see if the var is being parsed or not, it also says nothing. I replaced second line with echo "Working"; to check

Answer (score 0):

> Try this what is post on same page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['var_name'])) {
 print_r($_POST);
}
exit();
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="var_name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your html tag is wrong.
You need to set name to it like this

```
<input type= "submit" name= "submit">
```

Then when you submit your form like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// you will set your post var, try to print it with
print_r($_POST);

}
```

And you don't need to add "/" to the input, it will work without it.

And sorry, ive made syntax mistake, forgot to close if statement. Now is correct.

Comment: Sorry for being so lame, but should i add thatif(isset_ .. in test.php? If yeah, where? Sorry again, I'm very new to php..

Comment: Well.. yes.. that way you basicly check is submit button pressed..
And that way you submit form, and process it to "test.php"

Comment: Also @pbssubhash you access every form value in php with name atribute in html.

On the side.. Who the hell gave me -1 for answer, because it is correct??

Comment: Oh, I didn't mark -1 , BTW, The post works like charm with GET method. Does that change anything?

Comment: @pbssubhash 
well if you wanna use get, you need to change html, so method="GET"
Difference between POST and GET, is that, get vals will be in url, while post wont. Sorry Im little in hurry so this is rough explanation. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah I know, When I'm using method as get , I was able to parse the parameters correctly. 
But when I try with POSt changing the method to post, it doesn't work. In a secure point of view,I don't want sensitive info in the url as params